# como hacer multiples puntos en slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Hola tengo mi slider con puntos así

```
$('.slide_items').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    arrows: false,
});
```

y cuando corre hace focus en el DOT o posicion de la imagen en el que este, como puedo hacer que me marque los que ya recorrio tambien? es decir algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven esta en la imagen 4 y hay 4 puntos rellenos y los que faltan no estan rellenos, como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Los puntos son también enlaces ¿Qué pasa si salto del 1 al 4 por ejemplo sin pasar por el 2 y 3? ¿Qué ocurre si vuelvo atrás? Eso que quieres hacer es un comportamiento un poco raro para un slider.

Comment: no, solo quiero que se coloreen los puntos que están detrás del que estoy haciendo focus, si voy del 1 al 4 se colorean 1,2,3 y el 4 que estoy haciendo focus

Answer (score 0):

Fácil, pues existe un evento llamado `afterChange` que como el nombre lo dice, se ejecuta después de que la "slide" cambia, entonces podrías usarlo a tu favor para lograr lo que quieres:

```
$('.slide_items').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
   var i = 0;
   $('.slick-dots li').removeClass('active'); //remover la clase de active a todos para después agregársela a los que ya han pasado

   for(i = 0; i < (currentSlide + 1); i++){
      $('.slick-dots li').eq(i).addClass('active');
   }
});
```

Y ya en tu css podrías hacer lo siguiente, por ejemplo:

```
.slick-dots li{
   background-color: #000;
   opacity: 0.6;
}

.slick-dots li.active{
   background-color: #000;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Claro que los estilos tu los puedes manejar de la forma que quieras y necesites, solo fue un ejemplo.